# Connection PDO with SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to stablish a new `PDO` connection with `PHP MVC` and `SQL Server` but when I try to make a consult to my DB this send me a error

```
Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

I'm trying to make the connection as this

```
<?php

class Conexion{

  static public function conectar(){

    $DATABASE="Database";
    $DB_USER="DBUser";
    $DB_PASSWORD="DBPassword";
    $SERVER_NAME = "ServerName";
    try
    {
      $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$SERVER_NAME;Database=$DATABASE", "$DB_USER", "$DB_PASSWORD");
      $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo 'ERROR TO CONNECT' . $e->getMessage();
      die();
    }

  }

}
```

and in another controller I make the query as this

```
    <?php

require_once "conexion.php";

class UserModel{

    static public function mdlSearchUser($table, $data){
      $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT CB_CODIGO FROM $table WHERE CB_ACTIVO='S' AND CB_Codigo = $data");
      $stmt->execute();
      return $stmt -> fetchAll();
      $stmt ->close();
      $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a PDO instance that represent a connection to the requested database. You may try to change your `conexion.php` and return PDO instance with `return $db;` on success or `return false;` on error:

```
<?php
class Conexion {

    static public function conectar() {
        $DATABASE    = "tornado_tmp";
        $DB_USER     = "tornado";
        $DB_PASSWORD = "1234";
        $SERVER_NAME = "127.0.0.1\ikosoft,1066";
        try {
            $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$SERVER_NAME;Database=$DATABASE", "$DB_USER", "$DB_PASSWORD");
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            return $db;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR TO CONNECT' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And use your `Conexion` class like this:

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";

class UserModel{

    static public function mdlSearchUser($table, $data){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT CB_CODIGO FROM $table WHERE CB_ACTIVO='S' AND CB_Codigo = $data");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;
    }
}

$obj = new UserModel();
$obj->mdlSearchUser('table', 'data')
?>
```